# Getting flicker issue in Android app using Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm getting flicker issue in an Android Cordova Ionic app while navigating between pages. iOS ionic app is working fine without any flicker. App has side menu as well. Flicker is occurring if user is already login, then I am navigating user directly to home page

**SideMenu.html**

```
    <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" class="menu-page">
     <ion-side-menu-content>
     <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
     </ion-nav-buttons>
   </ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-side-menu-content>
 <ion-side-menu side="left" class="left-nav">

   <ion-content scroll="false"  has-bouncing="false">
     <div class="user-info text-center">

   </div>
      <ion-list>
           <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="app.menuscreen" ui-sref-active="selected">
             <i class="ion-home"></i><span>Home</span>
         </a>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
   </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**app.js**

```
       .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider

              .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/sidemenu.html',
           })

           .state('app.menuscreen', {
               url: '/menuscreen',
               views: {
                  'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/menuscreen.html',
                 }
            }
           })
```

**home.html**

```
            <ion-view> 
            <ion-content has-bouncing="false">

            <div class="button-box">
               <h2>Would you like to?</h2>
                <!--Button-->
                <div class="btn-box">
                    <div class="btn-parent-box">
                    <div class="icon">
                           <i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>
                       </div>
                        <button class="button button-full btn-orange"   type="submit"
                            ui-sref="newjob" title="New Job">New Job</button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/button-->
             </div>
            </ion-content> 
            </ion-view>
```